# close a windows if a page is 404

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, greasemonkey, http-status-code-404

if a page is not found, i want a script to close the window by itself.

I have no idea about how to start..a little bit of guide will be grateful

Comment: *Any* page? Would seem quite annoying to me to have my browser windows closed all the time if someone links incorrectly or I mistype a URL... :P

Comment: You have to know that JavaScript can **only** close windows that are being opened with `window.open()`

Comment: @teneff It's automatic closure if you previously used window.open(), but you should be prompted to confirm confirmation if window.open() wasn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @deceze's comment on your question. I'm not sure why you would want to close the window.

Technically speaking, it's possible to do.

If you control the website, you could alter the 404 page to perform a JavaScript `window.close()` although there are certain restrictions which are discussed [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml).

If you don't own the page, I suppose the only other way you could do it would be to write an extension/add-on/plug-in/doohickey for your browser. Again I'm not aware of any.

Assuming it's for a website that you control though, the normal practice isn't to close the window if your server sends a 404 but to instead provide positive feedback to the user.

Have a look at this article for some [404 best-practices](http://css-tricks.com/404-best-practices/).

Comment: actually, this will be used for 1 time purpose. it will not be used all times while browsing.

Comment: well sorry i mean tab, i didnt mean the whole browser window.

Comment: window.close() will attempt close the tab, rather than the entire browser.

Comment: and how do i specify in the if() statement if a 404 page has occured

Comment: A 404 error isn't returned by the page, the web server can't find a page and so returns the 404 response. Most web servers will also return html as the body of the response. You would create a web page (.htm for example) then change the settings on the web site to return this web page when the web server can't find what the user has requested (a 404). It's on this page that you create that you would place your JavaScript.

Comment: @Downvoter - please explain your reasons why you think this answer is not correct. @user478636 deserves the best information possible and if you don't think this answer covers it then it's in everyone's best interests to know why.